# getting error ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error

Tags: apache-pig

I wrote pig script as :

my_script.pig

```
bag_1 = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('|') AS (LN_NR:chararray,ET_NR:chararray,ET_ST_DT:chararray,ED_DT:chararray,PI_ID:chararray);
bag_2 = LIMIT  bag_1 $SIZE;
DUMP bag_2;
```

and made one param file as :

my_param.txt:

```
INPUT = hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/example
SIZE = 10
```

now, I am calling the script by

```
pig  my_param.txt  my_script.pig
```

this command but getting error as:

> ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error

any suggestions for that

Comment: Not sure if this is needed (perhaps it is even wrong), but it may expect strings to be quoted.  INPUT = 'hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/example'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the parameter file using **-m** or **-param_file** option. Refer the help documentation below.

```
$ pig --help
Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.7.1 (rexported)
compiled Nov 18 2014, 09:08:23

USAGE: Pig [options] [-] : Run interactively in grunt shell.
       Pig [options] -e[xecute] cmd [cmd ...] : Run cmd(s).
       Pig [options] [-f[ile]] file : Run cmds found in file.
  options include:
    -4, -log4jconf - Log4j configuration file, overrides log conf
    -b, -brief - Brief logging (no timestamps)
    -c, -check - Syntax check
    -d, -debug - Debug level, INFO is default
    -e, -execute - Commands to execute (within quotes)
    -f, -file - Path to the script to execute
    -g, -embedded - ScriptEngine classname or keyword for the ScriptEngine
    -h, -help - Display this message. You can specify topic to get help for that topic.
        properties is the only topic currently supported: -h properties.
    -i, -version - Display version information
    -l, -logfile - Path to client side log file; default is current working directory.
    -m, -param_file - Path to the parameter file
    -p, -param - Key value pair of the form param=val
    -r, -dryrun - Produces script with substituted parameters. Script is not executed.
    -t, -optimizer_off - Turn optimizations off. The following values are supported:
            SplitFilter - Split filter conditions
            PushUpFilter - Filter as early as possible
            MergeFilter - Merge filter conditions
            PushDownForeachFlatten - Join or explode as late as possible
            LimitOptimizer - Limit as early as possible
            ColumnMapKeyPrune - Remove unused data
            AddForEach - Add ForEach to remove unneeded columns
            MergeForEach - Merge adjacent ForEach
            GroupByConstParallelSetter - Force parallel 1 for "group all" statement
            All - Disable all optimizations
        All optimizations listed here are enabled by default. Optimization values are case insensitive.
    -v, -verbose - Print all error messages to screen
    -w, -warning - Turn warning logging on; also turns warning aggregation off
    -x, -exectype - Set execution mode: local|mapreduce, default is mapreduce.
    -F, -stop_on_failure - Aborts execution on the first failed job; default is off
    -M, -no_multiquery - Turn multiquery optimization off; default is on
    -P, -propertyFile - Path to property file
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the command correctly.

To use a property file, use **-param_file**  in the command:

```
pig -param_file <file> pig_script.pig
```

You can refer more details in the [Parameter Substitution](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution)